# Is there a word for when a problem's understood complexity grows exponentially as you work on it?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, phrase-requests

Example:

> Hey Joe, can you fix simple problem A?
>   Sure, Sally, no problem! After all it's simple, right?

But A is then found to have dependent sub-problems B and C; B to have dependent sub-problems D, E, and F; and C to have  dependent problems G and H.

> The problems have to be removed in alphabetical order.

Context: As a software developer, I run into problems like this while working on bugs in complex programs.

I wonder whether there's an English name for this concept.

Comment: *Can of worms* is close, but not an answer because the point of the image is that it is best not opened at all.

Comment: Pandora's box of von Neumann worms.

Comment: See also FUBAR, Charley-Foxtrot, et al.

Comment: A _hydra_ (but here the problem actually grew as a solution was attempted, rather than the estimate of the size of the problem/s). _The tip of the iceberg_ describes the problem as first appraised.

Comment: A decent analogy might be a fractal.  It, like some problems, just grows and grows and grows and grows . . ..    If time is money, then problem solving involves plenty of cost overruns, in both time AND money.  As they say, "No job is as easy as it looks at first."  There's more than a little truth in that aphorism!

Comment: "Situation Normal" ?

Comment: What ***precisely*** do you mean by “grows exponentially”? Please tell me you didn’t just use *exponentially* is some fuzzy, hand-wavy, non-mathematical way.  Pretty please.

Comment: @tchrist I was referring to the problem having the **potential** to grow exponentially in it's worst case, when every branch has it's own sub-branches, without end. If that doesn't qualify as exponentially then what term should I use there? I too am bothered to hear it used grossly out of context but thought I was correct.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think the hydra is a perfect analogy because the two new heads aren't exposed until you first attack the problem, and the more you attack, the more heads are created. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Snowball** is a verb meaning to increase rapidly or at an accelerating rate.

The present participle is **snowballing**.

Example: "Each problem led to other problems, with the size of the task snowballing so quickly that we couldn't manage it with the resources we had."

You might picture a snowball rolling down a hill. It starts out small, but with each revolution, it collects a layer of snow that has a volume that is proportional to its circumference. With each revolution, the circumference grows, and the mass of snow that is added is greater than the mass that was added in the previous revolution.

Answer (score 4):

I will continue to look for a single word to describe "when a problem's understood complexity grows exponentially as you work on it," but I found some phrases that might fit the bill.

[*Hofstadter's Law*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hofstadter%27s_law) is defined as:

> [A task] always takes longer than you expect, even when you take into account Hofstadter's Law.

Some more phrases to consider may be found in this list of [laws named after people](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_eponymous_laws). Another I think may work is 
[*Sod's Other Law*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sod%27s_law).

Answer (score 2):

It's a classic case of a problem *[spiraling out of control](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/spiral_12#spiraling)*.

> **spiral**, *v. intr.*: to continuously become worse, more, or less
>
> **spiral out of control**: *Crime has begun to spiral out of control in the capital.*

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps *unfolding complexity* describes the concept?